# Error munmap_chunk() - NetBeans 8.2

Tags: c++, linux, c, netbeans, gnu

```
#ifndef BUFFER_H
#define BUFFER_H

#include <string>
#include <cstring>



    class CBuffer
    {
    public:
        CBuffer():m_MaxLength(1024*10),m_OriMaxLength(m_MaxLength),m_pMsg(new char[m_MaxLength]), m_CurLen(0), m_LogLvl(0), m_GOLen(0)
        {}
        CBuffer(int size):m_MaxLength(size),m_OriMaxLength(m_MaxLength),m_pMsg(new char[m_MaxLength]), m_CurLen(0), m_LogLvl(0), m_GOLen(0)
        {}
        bool Append(std::string & str)
        {
            Append(str.c_str(),str.size());
            return true;
        }
        char* GetCurData(){
        return m_pMsg + m_GOLen;
    }
        int     GetDataLength(){
        return m_CurLen;
    }
        bool Append(const char * pData, int n32Length)
        {
//#include<iostream>
            //std::cout << "len " << n32Length;
//            while(m_CurLen + n32Length > m_MaxLength)
//            {
//                m_MaxLength *= 2;
//                m_pMsg = (char*)realloc(m_pMsg, m_MaxLength);
//            }
            std::memcpy(m_pMsg + m_CurLen,pData,n32Length);
            m_CurLen+= n32Length;
            return true;
        }
            void Clear(){
        if (m_MaxLength > m_OriMaxLength){
            delete []m_pMsg;
            m_pMsg = new char[m_OriMaxLength];
            m_MaxLength = m_OriMaxLength;
        }
        if (m_CurLen > 0){
            m_CurLen = 0;
        }
        m_GOLen = 0;
    }
        int m_LogLvl;
    private:
        char * m_pMsg;
        int m_GOLen;
        const int m_OriMaxLength;
        int m_CurLen;
        int m_MaxLength;


    };




#endif /* BUFFER_H */


std::string str = rMsg.SerializeAsString();
    if (pBuffer == NULL) return false;
    pBuffer->Append(str);
```

Ошибка

```
> *** Error in `/home/cucaracha/NetBeansProjects/GameMSServer/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/gamemsserver':
> munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00007faba0002540 ***
> ======= Backtrace: ========= /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7fabad4f67e5]
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x1a8)[0x7fabad503698]
> /home/cucaracha/NetBeansProjects/GameMSServer/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/gamemsserver[0x42ca09]
> /home/cucaracha/NetBeansProjects/GameMSServer/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/gamemsserver[0x445d7a]
> /home/cucaracha/NetBeansProjects/GameMSServer/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/gamemsserver[0x44cb8f]
> /home/cucaracha/NetBeansProjects/GameMSServer/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/gamemsserver[0x44a907]
> /home/cucaracha/NetBeansProjects/GameMSServer/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/gamemsserver[0x449f15]
> /home/cucaracha/NetBeansProjects/GameMSServer/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/gamemsserver[0x448f2f]
> /home/cucaracha/NetBeansProjects/GameMSServer/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/gamemsserver[0x447e69]
> /home/cucaracha/NetBeansProjects/GameMSServer/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/gamemsserver[0x41d4d4]
> /home/cucaracha/NetBeansProjects/GameMSServer/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/gamemsserver[0x42c93c]
> /home/cucaracha/NetBeansProjects/GameMSServer/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/gamemsserver[0x42d537]
> /home/cucaracha/NetBeansProjects/GameMSServer/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/gamemsserver[0x42d48b]
> /home/cucaracha/NetBeansProjects/GameMSServer/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/gamemsserver[0x42d301]
> /home/cucaracha/NetBeansProjects/GameMSServer/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/gamemsserver[0x42d11a]
> /home/cucaracha/NetBeansProjects/GameMSServer/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/gamemsserver[0x41d4d4]
> /home/cucaracha/NetBeansProjects/GameMSServer/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/gamemsserver[0x41939a]
> /home/cucaracha/NetBeansProjects/GameMSServer/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/gamemsserver[0x4225ff]
> /home/cucaracha/NetBeansProjects/GameMSServer/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/gamemsserver[0x422562]
> /home/cucaracha/NetBeansProjects/GameMSServer/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/gamemsserver[0x422186]
> /home/cucaracha/NetBeansProjects/GameMSServer/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/gamemsserver[0x421c10]
> /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.65.1(+0x3cf55)[0x7fabae777f55]
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x76ba)[0x7fabae2f56ba]
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7fabad5863dd]
> ======= Memory map: ======== 00400000-004c3000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 4982169                           
> /home/cucaracha/NetBeansProjects/GameMSServer/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/gamemsserver
> 006c2000-006c3000 r--p 000c2000 08:05 4982169                         
> /home/cucaracha/NetBeansProjects/GameMSServer/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/gamemsserver
> 006c3000-006c4000 rw-p 000c3000 08:05 4982169                         
> /home/cucaracha/NetBeansProjects/GameMSServer/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/gamemsserver
> 006c4000-006c5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0  02210000-02283000 rw-p
> 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
> 7faba0000000-7faba0021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
> 7faba0021000-7faba4000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
> 7faba7761000-7faba7762000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
> 7faba7762000-7faba7f62000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
> 7faba7f62000-7faba7f6d000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 4592261                 
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.23.so 7faba7f6d000-7faba816c000
> ---p 0000b000 08:05 4592261                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.23.so 7faba816c000-7faba816d000
> r--p 0000a000 08:05 4592261                   
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.23.so 7faba816d000-7faba816e000
> rw-p 0000b000 08:05 4592261                   
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.23.so 7faba816e000-7faba8174000
> rw-p 00000000 00:00 0  7faba8174000-7faba817f000 r-xp 00000000 08:05
> 4592271                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.23.so
> 7faba817f000-7faba837e000 ---p 0000b000 08:05 4592271                 
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.23.so 7faba837e000-7faba837f000
> r--p 0000a000 08:05 4592271                   
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.23.so 7faba837f000-7faba8380000
> rw-p 0000b000 08:05 4592271                   
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.23.so 7faba8380000-7faba8396000
> r-xp 00000000 08:05 4592255                   
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.23.so 7faba8396000-7faba8595000 ---p
> 00016000 08:05 4592255                   
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.23.so 7faba8595000-7faba8596000 r--p
> 00015000 08:05 4592255                   
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.23.so 7faba8596000-7faba8597000 rw-p
> 00016000 08:05 4592255                   
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.23.so 7faba8597000-7faba8599000 rw-p
> 00000000 00:00 0  7faba8599000-7faba85a1000 r-xp 00000000 08:05
> 4592257                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.23.so
> 7faba85a1000-7faba87a0000 ---p 00008000 08:05 4592257                 
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.23.so 7faba87a0000-7faba87a1000
> r--p 00007000 08:05 4592257                   
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.23.so 7faba87a1000-7faba87a2000
> rw-p 00008000 08:05 4592257                   
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.23.so 7faba87a2000-7faba87a9000
> r-xp 00000000 08:05 139893                    
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4 7faba87a9000-7faba89a8000
> ---p 00007000 08:05 139893                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4 7faba89a8000-7faba89a9000
> r--p 00006000 08:05 139893                    
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4 7faba89a9000-7faba89aa000
> rw-p 00007000 08:05 139893                    
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4 7faba89aa000-7faba89b3000
> r-xp 00000000 08:05 4592172                   
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.23.so 7faba89b3000-7faba8bb2000 ---p
> 00009000 08:05 4592172                   
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.23.so 7faba8bb2000-7faba8bb3000 r--p
> 00008000 08:05 4592172                   
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.23.so 7faba8bb3000-7faba8bb4000 rw-p
> 00009000 08:05 4592172                   
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.23.so 7faba8bb4000-7faba8be2000 rw-p
> 00000000 00:00 0  7faba8be2000-7faba8cb1000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 140662
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
> 7faba8cb1000-7faba8eb1000 ---p 000cf000 08:05 140662                  
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
> 7faba8eb1000-7faba8eb4000 r--p 000cf000 08:05 140662                  
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
> 7faba8eb4000-7faba8eb6000 rw-p 000d2000 08:05 140662                  
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
> 7faba8eb6000-7faba8eb7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
> 7faba8eb7000-7faba8efe000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 140178                  
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5.0.0 7faba8efe000-7faba90fd000
> ---p 00047000 08:05 140178                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5.0.0 7faba90fd000-7faba90ff000
> r--p 00046000 08:05 140178                    
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5.0.0 7faba90ff000-7faba9101000
> rw-p 00048000 08:05 140178                    
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5.0.0 7faba9101000-7faba9102000
> rw-p 00000000 00:00 0  7faba9102000-7faba9110000 r-xp 00000000 08:05
> 140160                    
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimbase.so.1.0.0
> 7faba9110000-7faba930f000 ---p 0000e000 08:05 140160                  
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimbase.so.1.0.0
> 7faba930f000-7faba9310000 r--p 0000d000 08:05 140160                  
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimbase.so.1.0.0
> 7faba9310000-7faba9311000 rw-p 0000e000 08:05 140160                  
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimbase.so.1.0.0
> 7faba9311000-7faba9338000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 140835                  
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0.0.0 7faba9338000-7faba9538000
> ---p 00027000 08:05 140835                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0.0.0 7faba9538000-7faba9539000
> r--p 00027000 08:05 140835                    
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0.0.0 7faba9539000-7faba953a000
> rw-p 00028000 08:05 140835                    
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0.0.0 7faba953a000-7faba95b9000
> r-xp 00000000 08:05 140026                    
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.3.0 7faba95b9000-7faba97b8000
> ---p 0007f000 08:05 140026                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.3.0 7faba97b8000-7faba97b9000
> r--p 0007e000 08:05 140026                    
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.3.0 7faba97b9000-7faba97ba000
> rw-p 0007f000 08:05 140026                    
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.3.0 7faba97ba000-7faba97ec000
> r-xp 00000000 08:05 140164                    
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4.2 7faba97ec000-7faba99eb000
> ---p 00032000 08:05 140164                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4.2 7faba99eb000-7faba99ec000
> r--p 00031000 08:05 140164                    
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4.2 7faba99ec000-7faba99ed000
> rw-p 00032000 08:05 140164                    
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4.2 7faba99ed000-7faba9a21000
> r-xp 00000000 08:05 140389                    
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6.2 7faba9a21000-7faba9c20000
> ---p 00034000 08:05 140389                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6.2 7faba9c20000-7faba9c22000
> r--p 00033000 08:05 140389                    
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6.2 7faba9c22000-7faba9c23000
> rw-p 00035000 08:05 140389                    
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6.2 7faba9c23000-7faba9c34000
> r-xp 00000000 08:05 140681                    
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6.5.1 7faba9c34000-7faba9e34000
> ---p 00011000 08:05 140681                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6.5.1 7faba9e34000-7faba9e35000
> r--p 00011000 08:05 140681                    
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6.5.1 7faba9e35000-7faba9e36000
> rw-p 00012000 08:05 140681                    
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6.5.1 7faba9e36000-7faba9e67000
> r-xp 00000000 08:05 131383                    
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11.6.15 7faba9e67000-7fabaa067000
> ---p 00031000 08:05 131383                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11.6.15 7fabaa067000-7fabaa068000
> r--p 00031000 08:05 131383                    
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11.6.15 7fabaa068000-7fabaa069000
> rw-p 00032000 08:05 131383                    
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11.6.15 7fabaa069000-7fabaa0c2000
> r-xp 00000000 08:05 140452                    
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0.1.0
> 7fabaa0c2000-7fabaa2c1000 ---p 00059000 08:05 140452                  
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0.1.0
> 7fabaa2c1000-7fabaa2cb000 r--p 00058000 08:05 140452                  
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0.1.0
> 7fabaa2cb000-7fabaa2cd000 rw-p 00062000 08:05 140452                  
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0.1.0
> 7fabaa2cd000-7fabaa2e2000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 140576                  
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18.1.0 7fabaa2e2000-7fabaa4e1000
> ---p 00015000 08:05 140576                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18.1.0 7fabaa4e1000-7fabaa4e2000
> r--p 00014000 08:05 140576                    
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18.1.0 7fabaa4e2000-7fabaa4e3000
> rw-p 00015000 08:05 140576                    
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18.1.0 7fabaa4e3000-7fabaa513000
> r-xp 00000000 08:05 140158                    
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4.1.0
> 7fabaa513000-7fabaa713000 ---p 00030000 08:05 140158                  
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4.1.0
> 7fabaa713000-7fabaa714000 r--p 00030000 08:05 140158                  
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4.1.0
> 7fabaa714000-7fabaa715000 rw-p 00031000 08:05 140158                  
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4.1.0
> 7fabaa715000-7fabaa716000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
> 7fabaa716000-7fabaa7b5000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 139595                  
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8.0.0 7fabaa7b5000-7fabaa9b4000
> ---p 0009f000 08:05 139595                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8.0.0 7fabaa9b4000-7fabaa9b5000
> r--p 0009e000 08:05 139595                    
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8.0.0 7fabaa9b5000-7fabaa9b8000
> rw-p 0009f000 08:05 139595                    
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8.0.0 7fabaa9b8000-7fabaaa3c000
> r-xp 00000000 08:05 140265                    
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26.0.0 7fabaaa3c000-7fabaac3b000
> ---p 00084000 08:05 140265                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26.0.0 7fabaac3b000-7fabaac3e000
> r--p 00083000 08:05 140265                    
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26.0.0 7fabaac3e000-7fabaac41000
> rw-p 00086000 08:05 140265                    
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26.0.0 7fabaac41000-7fabaac42000
> rw-p 00000000 00:00 0  7fabaac42000-7fabaac4a000 r-xp 00000000 08:05
> 140162                    
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0.1.0
> 7fabaac4a000-7fabaae49000 ---p 00008000 08:05 140162                  
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0.1.0
> 7fabaae49000-7fabaae4a000 r--p 00007000 08:05 140162                  
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0.1.0
> 7fabaae4a000-7fabaae4b000 rw-p 00008000 08:05 140162                  
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0.1.0
> 7fabaae4b000-7fabaae4e000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 4592223                 
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1.5 7fabaae4e000-7fabab04d000
> ---p 00003000 08:05 4592223                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1.5 7fabab04d000-7fabab04e000
> r--p 00002000 08:05 4592223                   
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1.5 7fabab04e000-7fabab04f000
> rw-p 00003000 08:05 4592223                   
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1.5 7fabab04f000-7fabab172000
> r-xp 00000000 08:05 133687                    
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30.6.2 tempRes :  RUN FINISHED;
> Aborted; core dumped; real time: 530ms; user: 0ms; system: 20ms
```

Answer (score 1):

Заметьте, что `m_pMsg` объявлен *до* `m_MaxLength`. Соответственно при вызове любого конструктора `m_pMsg` будет проинициализирован до `m_MaxLength` (даже несмотря на то, что в списке инициализации `m_MaxLength` идет раньше!) и такая инициализация `m_pMsg(new char[m_MaxLength])` приводит к неопределенному поведению. Также у класса отсутствует деструктор (память утекает), конструкторы и операторы копирования / перемещения (опять же можно нарваться на неопределенное поведение), ну и при записи в буффер нет проверок что в нем имеется достаточно места.